# Help Understanding L'Hospital rule proof from spivak

Tags: calculus

I didn't understand some considerations it does before proving such as:
 The Hypothesis that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}$ exists contain two implicit assumption:

"There is an interval $(a+\delta,a-\delta)$ such that $F'(x)$ and $G'(x)$ exist for all x in the interval except perhaps in $x=a$"

i disagree with this, since the limit only needs $a$ to be an accumulation point, so its not necessary that $F'(x)$ and $G'(x)$ exist for $\mathbf{ALL}$ $x$ in the interval

Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, but no..  For $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ to be defined, $f$ must be defined in some punctured interval about $a.$  Otherwise, the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit make no sense, does it?

Comment: Every time i discover one thing about limit definition... What is the Most rigorous definition in the world? the one i have here only says that $a$ must be a limit point and for all $x$ in the Domain if  0<|$x$-$a$|<$\delta$ so |$F(x)$-L|<$\epsilon$

Comment: For that definition to make sense, there must be *some* $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies that $f$ is defined at $x$.  That is to say, $f$ is defined on a punctured neighborhood of $a.$

Comment: but in the whole punctured neighborhood?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't make sense otherwise.  If there is no $\delta$ such that $f(x) is defined whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$ what does the definition mean?  How can a limit ever exist?

Comment: Fact, thank you so much. I wasnt visualizing it so well